# Spring boot - Jar signer information issue

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the following exception when starting the spring boot server.I see that the problem is related to javax.servlet.jsp package.Is there a way to force spring boot to use a specific jar for this package , in order to avoid this error? Please help me to get rid of this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.Application.main(Application.java:43)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class
 "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.(JspRuntimeContext.java:123)    ... 18 more
```

Please find my pom.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-  4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>libs-releases</id>
            <url>http://nexus.ab11.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>libs-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://nexus.ab11.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                    <additionalConfig>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</name>
                            <location>${main.basedir}/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                        <file>
                            <name>.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</name>
                            <location>${main.basedir}/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs</location>
                        </file>
                    </additionalConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.security.egd>file:/dev/./urandom</java.security.egd>
                        <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--  <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.1</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
             <id>enforce</id>
             <configuration>
               <rules>
                 <DependencyConvergence/>
               </rules>
             </configuration>
             <goals>
               <goal>enforce</goal>
             </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
       </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ab11.cslt</groupId>
            <artifactId>CSLT-Ranjith</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.c2s2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <!--            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            </exclusion> -->
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ab11.cslt</groupId>
            <artifactId>CSLT-Ranjith</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.c2s2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::jetty[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::jetty[] -->
        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>libs-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://nexus.ab11.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>libs-releases</id>
            <url>http://nexus.ab11.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-public</id>
            <url>http://nexus.ab11.com/nexus/content/groups/public-all/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Also please find the servlet jars in my dependency tree below.

```
mvn dependency:tree |grep servlet

^@[INFO] |  |  \-
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.15.v20140411:compile [INFO] | 
|           +-
 org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO] |     +-
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.2.0.v201112011158:compile
[INFO] |     +-
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211821:compile
```

Comment: Please post all versions you're using. There was an issue with a combination of an early Boot and the 4.0 series, but it's been fixed for a while.

Comment: Please use proper formatting next time that way the post and the code will remain readable. The `>` is used for quotes not for posting code.

Comment: For your error make sure that you don't have included any jar that contain `javax.servlet` classes.